# PhpWord produced corrected file when using a while loop

Tags: phpword

I am using PhpWord to generate a .docx file and it works fine until I use a while loop.  I'm sure it is something simple I'm missing about using the tables/rows, but I haven't been able to find a specific answer.  If I comment out the while and leave the rest intact, it works fine.  It is something with the loop that causes a problem.  I tried having the addTable() outside of the while loop as well, no difference other than my addText("Step ".... shows up after the table instead of before where I want it.  I've tried different combinations but was hoping that someone here would have an idea if I have to somehow close the table or something before it loops or what??  Thanks.

```
$y=1;
$z=1;
While ($z<=count($me_events)) {
    $section->addText($me_events[$z] . " (Protocol ID: " . $me_pid[$z] . ")", array('name' => 'Arial', 'size' => 10));
    $section->addText("me_pid is set to " . $me_pid[$z] . " and sprot_id is set to " . $sprot_id[$y]);
    if($me_pid[$z] == $sprot_id[$y]) {
        while ($me_pid[$z] == $sprot_id[$y]) {
            $section->addText("Step " . $sorder[$y] . " - " . $sdesc[$y] . " (Step Wait: " . $swait[$y] . ")");
            $table = $section->addTable($tableStyle);
            $table->addRow();
            if ($ctext[$y]=="") {
                $table->addCell(8000)->addText("\t" . $sscript[$y]);
            } else {
                $table->addCell(8000)->addText("\t" . $ctext[$y]);
                if ($sscript[$y]<>"") {
                    $table->addCell(8000)->addText("\t" . $sscript[$y]);
                }
            }
            $y++;
            $section->addTextBreak(1);
        }
    }
    $section->addPageBreak();
    $z++;
}
```

Comment: one possible explanation is that some text in one of your arrays contains some invalid characters. I.e. please try updating all the `addText` parts in your code to convert the potential special characters from your contents:
`addText(htmlspecialchars("your text here", ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));`

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  My variables did have embedded HTML in them.

Comment: Ok now the next problem....the variables $sscript and $ctext can contain embedded HTML or formatting like carriage returns, new paragraphs, etc.  I've tried to use addHtml but I get nothing in the result.  I need to preserve the formatting in these variables.  Is there a way to do this?   example:  <b>New Agent</b> Contact with new information and forms. <br><br> Call with updated <i> Support </i> phone numbers. <br>

Answer (score 1):

ok, so moving the answers to an actual answer instead of just comments.

Question 1 (addText fails inside loop)

addText fails when you have html / special characters inside so in general one should use:

```
addText(htmlspecialchars("your text here", ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));
```

Question 2 (how to use addHtml to insert the html content to cells)

you can use addHtml to insert contents to containers - in this case to the table cells like this:

```
$cell = $table->addCell(8000);
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($cell, "<strong>HTML CONTENT</strong><br/><em>test</em>");
```

please note that the `addHtml` doesn't seem to recognize `<b>` & `<i>` tags but it does recognize the `<strong>` & `<em>` ones. Additionally instead of `<br>` you need to use `<br/>` (if the html data comes outside of your reach I assume that you can easily search & replace these tags).

Comment: Is there a list anywhere that shows what html tags that the addHtml() supports?

Comment: the addHtml uses DOMDocument to parse the html so you can try to check from there. Or by just testing if you have a limited number of tags that you're using (you should also double check whether it works with those <i> & <b> tags - for me those tags didn't have any effect when opening the docx with libreoffice)

Answer (score 0):

I used str_replace to remove the `<b>` and `</b>` tags from my code, and we're already using the `<br/>`, so it is working fine without bolding the output.  But that's acceptable to me, so I consider this resolved.  Thank you for your assistance!!